# rasa unable to detect luis entities of regex, list type

Tags: azure-language-understanding, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am using LUIS model(exported as json file) to build rasa_nlu using command "rasa train --out models\test.tar.gz"

Luis model has entities of type list and regex, which rasa_nlu model is unable to extract.

for example:
LUIS Entity name: "Animal"
LUIS Entity Type: "List"
Elements in list would be like cat, dog, etc...

If i present string like "How to train dog"?

I am expecting "dog" to be mapped to "Animal" entity just like how LUIS does but rasa_nlu doesn't detect "dog" as entity since it is of type "list". If entity type is changed to "simple" rasa_nlu detects dog and classifies it as "Animal" entity type

Similarly, if luis entity type is of regex identified by "0x[a-f,0-9]{8}/i", rasa_nlu fails to detect it.

Are there any issues with rasa_nlu in detecting luis regex and list entity types or am i doing anything wrong?

below are the contents of json file used to train rasa

```
{
  "luis_schema_version": "3.2.0",
  "versionId": "0.1",
  "name": "Test",
  "desc": "",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "tokenizerVersion": "1.0.0",
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "error"
    },
    {
      "name": "None"
    },
    {
      "name": "wild"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [],
  "composites": [],
  "closedLists": [
    {
      "name": "animal",
      "subLists": [
        {
          "canonicalForm": "dog",
          "list": []
        },
        {
          "canonicalForm": "cat",
          "list": []
        }
      ],
      "roles": []
    }
  ],
  "patternAnyEntities": [],
  "regex_entities": [
    {
      "name": "ecode",
      "regexPattern": "0x[a-f,0-9]{8}",
      "roles": []
    }
  ],
  "prebuiltEntities": [],
  "model_features": [],
  "regex_features": [],
  "patterns": [],
  "utterances": [
    {
      "text": "error 0x80070055",
      "intent": "error",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "error while browsing 0x90909090",
      "intent": "error",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "how to train cat",
      "intent": "wild",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "how to train dog",
      "intent": "wild",
      "entities": []
    }
  ],
  "settings": []
}
```

appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you share what the training data you are feeding to Rasa NLU looks like?

Also, going forward, it'd be great if you could post your questions on the Rasa forum as there are more people there and you're more likely to get help quicker (http://forum.rasa.com).

Comment: i've posted it on rasa forums as well.   https://forum.rasa.com/t/rasa-unable-to-detect-luis-entities-of-regex-list-type/15528?u=prasad-pillutla